# Trouble displaying a graph of a Lissajous curve

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

wrote a program to graph Lissajous curves but for whatever reason when the graph is shown it's blank. Is there something I missed?

```
#this program given a set of parameters calculates and graphs Lissajous Curves

from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import *

t=arange(0,4*pi/200)
#first set of parameters
A=1
B=1
a1=1
b1=2
d=pi/2
#second set of parameters
a2=2
b2=3
X1=[]
Y1=[]
Y2=[]
X2=[]
x1=A*sin(a1*t+d)
y1=B*sin(b1*t)
x2=A*sin(a2*t+d)
y2=B*sin(b2*t)
X1=append(X1,x1)
Y1=append(Y1,y1)
X2=append(X2,x2)
Y2=append(Y2,y2)
figure()
plot(t,X1, color='blue')
plot(t,Y1, color='pink')
plot(t,X2, color='purple')
plot(t,Y2, color='green')
show()
```

details
details
details
details

Comment: try calling `print(X1)` and see if it's really what you expect it to be.

Comment: 1 is the only value displayed, what could it be?

Comment: well, how do you define X1? Try printing the variables you use for that. If you iterate that procedure a few times I'm sure you'll find the error. (hint: it's right in the beginning)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import *

t=arange(0,4*pi/2,0.0001)
print(t)
#first set of parameters
A=1
B=1
a1=1
b1=2
d=pi/2
#second set of parameters
a2=2
b2=3
X1=[]
Y1=[]
Y2=[]
X2=[]
for i in range(len(t)):
    x1=A*sin(a1*t[i]+d)
    y1=B*sin(b1*t[i])
    x2=A*sin(a2*t[i]+d)
    y2=B*sin(b2*t[i])
    X1=append(X1,x1)
    Y1=append(Y1,y1)
    X2=append(X2,x2)
    Y2=append(Y2,y2)
figure()
plot(t,X1, color='blue')
plot(t,Y1, color='pink')
plot(t,X2, color='purple')
plot(t,Y2, color='green')
show()
```

Comment: This answer is good in that it solves the problem, but it's not very informative and doesn't really answer the question. The poster asked if there was something they missed. Indeed, they missed the `0.0001` second argument in arange, but everything else they did is basically identical.

Comment: Also, you definitely _shouldn't_ be looping through the entries of `t` in your example: numpy is implicitly doing this in the OPs example already, and much more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Shep. I will try to be more informative next time.

Answer (score 0):

To make this a [Lissajou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) we have to plot X vs Y and not t. Using the hints from the comments that leads to

```py
#this program given a set of parameters calculates and graphs Lissajous Curves

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, plot, show
from math import pi

t=np.arange(0, 4 * pi / 2, 0.001)

#first set of parameters
A = 1
B = 1
a1 = 1
b1 = 2
d = pi/2

#second set of parameters
a2 = 2
b2 = 3

X1 = A * np.sin(a1 * t + d)
Y1 = B * np.sin(b1 * t)

X2 = A * np.sin(a2 * t + d)
Y2 = B * np.sin(b2 * t)

figure()
plot(X1, Y1, color='blue')
plot(X2, Y2, color='pink')
show()
```

[image]